# Future of Developing e Learning content using Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, adobe

Is it a good practice to use Adobe Flash to develop e Learning content?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

No. Adobe will be ending support by the year 2020 and urges people to use other formats.

https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/25/16026236/adobe-flash-end-of-support-2020